# Docker compose: reach back end from frontend javascript request in different containers

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx, axios

I'm setting up a little web project with docker-compose. the front is a VueJS served by a nginx server in the container named frontend, and the back is a NestJS in the container named main. Both are run with a `docker-compose.yml` file, both are in the same network, and both can reach each other (a `curl http://main:3000` from the frontend container works).

This is all good until I start working on the JS in my Vue to make backend requests. I'm trying to reach the container (a GET request on my NestJS) but the question is: How do I do this ? Because the request in itself doesn't come from inside the container but my browser, so I can't find a way to reach the container.

First problem: How can I get the ip address I must send the requests to (the address of the `main` container)
Second problem: How do I avoid the CORS issue of my browser blocking my requests ?

Those questions may seem easy for people who may know docker, nginx or JS but I admit not really understanding nginx and Docker very well so even links to documentation may help.

Notes:
The nginx of my frontend container uses the default `nginx.conf` for I don't know what can I change to make it work.
The backend is served by an nginx but if it can solve the problem I'll gladly do so

Comment: Not an expert myself, but you could configure the nginx of your frontend to also act as a reverse proxy to your backend. that way all request go through the same URL and no cors issues appear.

Comment: I've tried a bit (I think ?) using the location /api { proxy_pass http://main:3000; } But I couldn't find a way to make it work (I ended up with an error 500 on my whole page. I haven't asked about this because I know this is juste an issue of wrong configuration

Comment: I successfully setup a reverse proxy which does send my requests to my back end ! thank you @Sirko. Now all my requests sent to http://172.18.0.6/api are redirected to my backend. I just have a slight issue, how do I get this 172.18.0.6 which is the address of my frontend container ?

Comment: By default docker uses the IP address of the host machine. But you links should always be relative anyways, if possible. So instead of `172.18.0.6/api` you should just use `/api` wherever possible.

Comment: OHH I didn't know that that fixes everything ! Thanks a billion @Sirko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sirko pointed out in the comments, the easiest way to solve this problem it to use a reverse proxy.
By setting a reverse proxy such as:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://main:3000/;
}
```

doing request to the address `/api/` will forward all the requests to the backend so `/api/users` will end up as `http://main:3000/users` and so the ip is resolved by docker and because the request goes through the server, there is no CORS issue.